# RStudio (v. 1.2.1335) cannot start in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: r, rstudio

I have just installed update version of Ubuntu v.1.2.1335. However, it cannot work properly. 
Here is the error:

sudo rstudio

Error:
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
[11095:11095:0424/090516.456076:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.

I have checked the link and found this:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=638180.

Please, kindly help.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error due to installing .deb file (1.2.1335) by double-clicking it while previous versions of RStudio were installed from the command line as root. It caused conflicts which I couldn't fix by uninstalling and installing RStudio. I also tried changing permissions but it was a pain.

Getting the developmental version of RStudio (1.2.1522) solved the problem.

Instructions:

1. Remove RStudio with `sudo apt-get --purge remove rstudio`
2. Download the appropriate [deb](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/) file. Future stable releases should work as well.
3. Install the latest version with `sudo dpkg -i rstudio-1.2.1522-amd64.deb` (using the appropriate file name)